# How to use multiple Pipes with gulp-if and lazypipe?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-useref, gulp-if

I have a Grunt file that is working without using gulpif and lazypipes, but what I am trying to do is create a task that will take in the script files in my index.html page using `useref`.  Then `gulpif` JS `lint`, `uglify`/concatenate, and `notify`.  I am getting a "Error: Invalid call to lazypipe().." and I was looking at this post https://github.com/OverZealous/lazypipe/issues/19, but I am a bit green and don't understand the error/how to fix it "pipe(foo) vs. pipe(foo())".  **If someone could tell me how I am using the lazypipe wrong = I should be good.**

The grunt file is bigger and I am using gulpif bc css will used too once this is to work.  If there is a better way for me to do this let me know, thanks.

Plugins in use:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
jshint          = require('gulp-jshint'),
notify          = require('gulp-notify'),
gulpif          = require('gulp-if'),
lazypipe        = require('lazypipe'),
useref          = require('gulp-useref');
uglify          = require('gulp-uglify');

var anyJS       = '/**/*.js',
    distFolder  = 'dist';

//Lazy Tasks
    var jsTask = lazypipe()
        .pipe(jshint)
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
        .pipe(notify('JS Linting finished'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(notify('JS Compressing finished'));


//Tasks
    gulp.task('mini', function () {
        return gulp.src('./index.html')
            .pipe(useref())
            .pipe(gulpif(anyJS, jsTask()))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured out what was wrong.  All function calls in the LazyPipe must not use ()!  So if you have lazypipe().pipe(jshint).pipe(uglify()).  It will not work - you need to remove the () on uglify too.

I think I'll try it again with LP and GF, but here is it working with gulpFilter or at least 90%.  The notifies didn't show.

```
gulp.task('mini', function () {
    var jsFilter = gulpFilter(jsInput, {restore: true});
    var cssFilter = gulpFilter(cssInput, {restore: true});

    return gulp.src('./index.html')
        .pipe(plumber({
            handleError: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(notify('JS task finished'))
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoPrefixer('last 2 versions'))
        .pipe(cssComb())
        .pipe(mmq({
            log: true
        }))
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(notify('CSS task finished'))
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore)

        .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you pointed out in your own answer, you need to use the stream factories themselves (instead of the result) when you pipe with `lazypipe`. For factories that uses no parameter, this is as simple as removing the `()`, and for factories that do require parameters, you can use arrow functions to create such factories:

```js
var jsTask = lazypipe()
    .pipe(jshint)
    .pipe(() => jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
    .pipe(() => notify('JS Linting finished'))
    .pipe(uglify)
    .pipe(() => notify('JS Compressing finished'));
```

It is also possible to create such factories by using `bind()`, but the approach above is easier as you don't need to worry about the calling context.